# JSF - Ajax call - What is it wrong on this code?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, javabeans

I think the best way to resolve this problem is just to paste my code :

`Selector bean`

```
@ManagedBean(name="selector")
@RequestScoped
public class Selector {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.page}")
    private String page;
    private String profilePage;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if(profilePage==null || profilePage.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.profilePage="main";
        }

        if(page==null || page.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.page="homepage";
        }
    }

    public String getProfilePage() { System.out.println("GET ="+profilePage); return profilePage; }
    public void setProfilePage(String profilePage) { this.profilePage=profilePage; }

    public String getPage() { return page; }
    public void setPage(String page) { this.page=page; }
}
```

`profile.xhtml`

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="profileContent">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{selector.profilePage=='main'}">
        <ui:include src="/profile/profile_main.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{selector.profilePage=='edit'}">
        <ui:include src="/profile/profile_edit.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

`profile_main.xhtml`

```
<h:form id="formProfileMain" prependId="false">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">
        <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head" />

        <h:outputLabel value="MAIN" />

        <h:panelGroup layout="block" >
            <h:commandButton value="Edit Button">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{selector.profilePage}" value="edit" />
                <f:ajax event="action" render=":profileContent"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

`profile_edit.xhtml`

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="profileEditContent">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{selector.profilePage=='edit'}">
        <h:form id="formProfileEdit" prependId="false">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head" />

                <h:outputLabel value="EDIT" />

                <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                    <h:commandButton value="Confirm Edit">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{selector.profilePage}" value="editConfirm" />
                        <f:ajax event="action" render=":profileEditContent"/>
                    </h:commandButton>

                    <h:commandButton value="Back">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{selector.profilePage}" value="main" />
                        <f:ajax event="action" render=":profileEdit"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{selector.profilePage=='editConfirm'}">
        <h:outputLabel value="FINALLY IM HERE" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

If i click first on **Edit Button** and than on **Confirm Edit**, i attempt to get (as result) the page with the label **FINALLY IM HERE**
Unfortunatly this doesnt happen. I click on **Edit Button** and after, if i click on **Confirm Edit**, nothing happen.

What am I wrong? Cheers

**UPDATE WITH NEW VERSION**

`bean`

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProfileSelector {
    private String profilePage;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if(profilePage==null || profilePage.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.profilePage="main";
        }
    }

    public String getProfilePage() { return profilePage; }
    public void setProfilePage(String profilePage) { this.profilePage=profilePage; }
}
```

`profile.xhtml`

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="profileContent">
    <h:form id="formProfile" prependId="false">
        <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head" />

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{profileSelector.profilePage=='main'}">
            <ui:include src="/profile/profile_main.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{profileSelector.profilePage=='edit'}">
            <ui:include src="/profile/profile_edit.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

`profile_main.xhtml`

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block">            
    <h:outputLabel value="MAIN" />

    <h:panelGroup layout="block">
        <h:commandButton value="Edit Button">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSelector.profilePage}" value="edit" />
            <f:ajax event="action" render=":profileContent"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

`profile_edit.xhtml`

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="profileContentEdit">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{profileSelector.profilePage=='edit'}">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">                
            <h:outputLabel value="EDIT" />

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="profilo_3">
                <h:commandButton value="Confirm Edit">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSelector.profilePage}" value="editConfirm" />
                    <f:ajax event="action" render=":profileContentEdit"/>
                </h:commandButton>

                <h:commandButton value="Back">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSelector.profilePage}" value="main" />
                    <f:ajax event="action" render=":profileContent"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{profileSelector.profilePage=='editConfirm'}">
        <h:outputLabel value="FINALLY Im HERE" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that gets complicated. Whether the `UICommand` action will be invoked also depends on the result of the `rendered` attribute of the component or one of its parents. Because the bean is in the request scope the `profilePage` defaults back to `main` in the next request, so the `rendered` attribute of the edit section evaluates `false`, so the buttons in the edit section will not invoke any actions. This has been answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291849/jsf-can-postconstruct-block-setter-method-by-using-an-ajax-call).

In theory, marking the bean `@ViewScoped` should fix this because it retains the bean state in subsequent views. However, in your particular case there are two problems which prevents it from working properly.

First, you're using a `@ManagedProperty` which refers to a value which is in a shorter scope (the `#{param}` is basically request scoped). You would need to split the `profilePage` into another bean and mark this `@ViewScoped`.

Second, due to a currently still open bug in JSF2 ([issue 1718](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1718)), your particular case would still not work because you have multiple `<h:form>` in a different `rendered` condition which are all attached to the same bean. This specific situation would lead to `javax.faces.ViewState` being completely missing in the returned response. This will cause the view scoped bean to be garbaged and recreated (and the `profilePage` defaults to `main` again). As a temporary workaround, you need to extract and merge the forms into one form in `profile.xhtml`, as direct child of the first `<h:panelGroup>`.

---

**Update**: If your sole concern is that you want to connect the beans to each other, then you could split the beans as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Selector {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.page}")
    private String page;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{profileSelector}")
    private ProfileSelector profileSelector;

    // ...
}
```

---

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProfileSelector {
    private String profilePage;

    // ...
}
```

The view scoped bean is then accessible in the request scoped bean this way.

Or, if you *really* want to have a single bean, you can as a workaround also replace `@ManagedProperty` as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Selector {
    private String page;
    private String profilePage;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        page = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequestParameterMap().get("page");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ohh. At least now I understand why it create component tree with "main" at the begin of the procession. I think i need to change strategy, because i want the selector bean with RequestScope :) Unfortunatly i don't see any other ways to implements my dinamic menu with ajax call with jsf...

Comment: You really want `@ViewScoped`. See answer update how to approach this.

Comment: Yeah, i split in two different bean (a best visibility). Tried but at the moment it doest load the rendered. I'll try some more!

Comment: Now, i have 2 bean. I need to put a only one global form too? In fact i've dont understand why it doesnt work with many form in many rendered :)

Comment: Yes, you need to have a form  which is placed *outside* the parts with `rendered` conditions which is bound to the same bean. As suggested in the answer, put it in `profile.xhtml`.

Comment: In fact it's strange that when i first click on Edit Button it load my second page (profileEditContent). In fact, in the first phase, it should find only "main" on profilePage. (and the rendered of profileEditContent should be totally ignored). But it LOAD that content... :)

Comment: Because the `main` form is been rendered, it can invoke the button.

Comment: Ah ok. That's strange too is that sometimes i need to click on Edit Button 2 times to load the profile_edit.xhtml page. It looks like that it can't render it. I'll try now to put all in a form :)

Comment: Tried. Now i get the error : malformedXML: INVALID_STATE_ERR: Dom Exception 11.

Comment: That's just a XML syntax error. Did you remove **any** `<h:form>` *and* `</h:form>`?

Comment: yes. I just have those. (and yes, someone else in others page that doesnt mean with this).

Comment: It works if i remove `<f:ajax event="action" render=":profileContentEdit"/>` and `<f:ajax event="action" render=":profileContent"/>` on `profile_edit.xhtml` . Looks like it doesnt find the ajax library?

Comment: Remove `prependId="false"` from `<h:form>` and retry.

Comment: Also, netbeans say (when i click on Edit Profile) : `GRAVE: javax.faces.FacesException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':profileContentEdit' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt128` (and `j_idt128` doesnt exist on my HTML Source)

Comment: I checked your code update: there are 2 problems: First, `:profileContentEdit` can indeed not be located from that point. It's at the same level. Remove the `:` prefix. Second, the edit include is not rendered when the `profilePage` is `editConfirm`. Use `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{profileSelector.profilePage=='edit' || profileSelector.profilePage=='editConfirm'}">` instead.

Comment: OHH nice finally it works :) so `:` refeer to the level before. Like `.` syntax when i search a root path :) Nice one man, thanks again.

Comment: Any `UINamingContainer` component brings extra level in. The `<h:form>` is one of them.

Comment: I speak too soon (arghh). It work perfect when the Bean is instantiate the first time (as ViewScope). When i load the page for the first time, i need to click 2 time on Edit Profile...! Do you understand what i mean? I hope so...

Comment: The need to click two times is a sign that the viewscoped bean get garbaged during the first time (i.e. `javax.faces.ViewState` is missing). How do you "load page for first time"? Is there more into the code which is left out the question?

Comment: Yeah, in fact i load profile.xhtml on the Content after check if the user isLogged(). I think i need to call the setter of the ProfileSelector when i check the login... (so it will include in the viewscoped). I'll open a new question on stackoverflow :)