# JSF 2.0 : Ajax call from the rendered component to managed bean failure

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, listener

Iam using JSF2.0 wherein Iam rendering a  group of components using ajax  based on a user activity on that page .This works fine however,after the component gets rendered, iam performing an ajax call again based on user activity within this rendered component This is where my ajax call is failing .I have done the same implementation in both scenarios but no idea why its failing .Could someone help me figure out the error  ?

following is the code :

first ajax call :

```
 <h:commandLink id="addMultiple" value="Add" >                  
<f:ajax execute="addMultiple" render="additionalField " listener="#{Bean.doAddMultiple}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Rendered component :

```
 <h:panelGroup id = "additionalField"   > 
 <h:outputText  value="New Field:"  rendered="#{Bean.multiple eq 'true'}" />
 <h:inputText style="width:10%" value="#{Bean.Number}"  rendered="#{Bean.multiple eq 'true'}" />
<h:commandButton id="add" value = "Add"  rendered="#{Bean.multiple eq 'true'}">
<f:ajax event="click" execute="add" render="textBoxes" listener="#{Bean.doaddTextboxes}"/>  
</h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The above component is rendered fine .
I have the "textBoxes" component in the  same form as well as the managed bean method taking AJaxBehaviour event as the parameter also  .But the issue here is the second AJAX call is not even fired .what is the issue here ?

Comment: what scope are you using for `Bean`?

Comment: its request scoped .but still the first Ajax call works and only the second one doesnt work and both calls are referencing the same bean .

Comment: change it to `@ViewScoped` , in general ajax better be done with `@ViewScoped`... cause new instance of the bean created upon each submit

Comment: Also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4294096/617373 and this http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html

Comment: On an additional note the second ajax call happens successfully but if i again change the Bean.Number value and  make an ajax call "viewExpired" exception arises even though we havent navigated to a different view .Any idea on that ?

Comment: you using any `action` that reurns any string? or ""?

Comment: the Ajaxbehaviour action method returns nothing

Comment: Try asking a new question with a detailed scenario/code sample...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `@ViewScoped` , in general ajax better be done with atlesat `@ViewScoped`... cause new instance of the bean created upon each submit...

Also take a look at this [JSF - Ajax call - What is it wrong on this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292330/jsf-ajax-call-what-is-it-wrong-on-this-code/4294096#4294096) and this [The benefits and pitfalls of @ViewScoped](http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html)

Also , take a look at **BalusC** and **Arjan Tijms** answers over here JSF - [Can @PostConstruct block setter method by using an ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291849/jsf-can-postconstruct-block-setter-method-by-using-an-ajax-call)