# prime face data table with pagination and data table is put inside Tab

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

every row I have a commandbutton for editing the row. The method action of this commandbutton sets a managed bean property to hide the datatable and to show the edit form. I do this by enclosing the datatable in a panelgroup, and the edit form in another one, and setting the rendered attribute of the panelgroups accordingly to the managed bean property.

The managed bean is Viewscoped, and all the requests I have are non-ajax.

When I click the edit commandbutton on a row of the 1st datatable page, everything works ok.

But if I move to another datatable page using the paginator links, and then I click the edit commandbutton on any row of the page, it doesn't work, because the Viewscoped bean is created again (PostConstruct is triggered), and even I can see that the action method of the clicked commandbutton isn't executed.

I think it has to do with the ajax requests of the paginator (I guess).

Anybody knows how to make it work?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: The thing is i am not using lazy data model to load data table and the actionlistener which has been binded to each row workd only first page of pagonation and for sub sequent page teh edit button fails call the action listener on click?What migt be the issue do u have any idea

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `rendered` attribute. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816035/jsf-2-0-ajax-call-from-the-rendered-component-to-managed-bean-failure).

A beter way of solving your problem is to make an [editable datatable](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml?jfwid=29534), or if your object is more complex, make your edit page a [dialog](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/df/data.xhtml?jfwid=29534), and open it with your edit button.